# Ubuntu + Apache + .htaccess: Hide from Google

Tags: .htaccess, apache-2.4, ubuntu-14.10

How do I edit the .htaccess file in the folder www/owncloud/ to set:
X-Robots-Tag to "noindex, nofollow"
(Using header rather than robots.txt according to: https://yoast.com/x-robots-tag-play/)

Have tried this, but I cannot see the X-Robots-Tag set to anything other than: none in Chrome.

```
<IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
<IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
<IfModule mod_headers.c>

Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex,nofollow"

SetEnvIfNoCase ^Authorization$ "(.+)" XAUTHORIZATION=$1
RequestHeader set XAuthorization %{XAUTHORIZATION}e env=XAUTHORIZATION
</IfModule>
</IfModule>
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
php_value upload_max_filesize 513M
php_value post_max_size 513M
php_value memory_limit 512M
php_value mbstring.func_overload 0
<IfModule env_module>
SetEnv htaccessWorking true
</IfModule>
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule .* - [env=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteRule ^\.well-known/host-meta /public.php?service=host-meta [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^\.well-known/host-meta\.json /public.php?service=host-meta-json [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^\.well-known/carddav /remote.php/carddav/ [R]
RewriteRule ^\.well-known/caldav /remote.php/caldav/ [R]
RewriteRule ^apps/calendar/caldav\.php remote.php/caldav/ [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^apps/contacts/carddav\.php remote.php/carddav/ [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^remote/(.*) remote.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_mime.c>
AddType image/svg+xml svg svgz
AddEncoding gzip svgz
</IfModule>
<IfModule dir_module>
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
</IfModule>
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
Options -Indexes
<IfModule pagespeed_module>
ModPagespeed Off
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex,nofollow"

There is nothing wrong with that line, however you do have it within 3 IfModule's. Are you sure you have all 3 of these modules?

```
<IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
<IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
```

You might want to make sure you have all 3, or move the header set to another location in your file.
Also make sure it is the correct .htaccess and that AllowOverride is turned on for that directory.

Comment: I put it after the 3 IfModules:
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex,nofollow"
    </IfModule>
It seems to work well! Thanks!